# Determine number of entries matching a given value, grouped by column

Tags: python, pandas

Consider the following data.

```
Species,Gene,ExonCount
Amel,g1,3
Amel,g2,1
Amel,g3,5
Sinv,g4,1
Sinv,g5,1
Sinv,g6,2
Sinv,g7,2
```

I would like to determine the number of entries with exon count = 1, grouped by species. This is what I've come up with so far.

```
import io
import pandas

instream = io.StringIO("""Species,Gene,ExonCount
Amel,g1,3
Amel,g2,1
Amel,g3,5
Sinv,g4,1
Sinv,g5,1
Sinv,g6,2
Sinv,g7,2
""")

data = pandas.read_csv(instream)

for spec in data['Species'].unique():
    ones = sum([1 for x in data.loc[(data.Species == spec)]['ExonCount'] if x == 1])
    print(spec, ones)
```

It seems to work correctly, but is not elegant and I'm guessing it's not efficient on large dataframes. Is there a better / cleaner / more Pythonic way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

filter the df and then call [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and [`size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html):

```
In [43]:
data[data['ExonCount']==1].groupby('Species').size()

Out[43]:
Species
Amel    1
Sinv    2
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Ughh...too easy. Should have thought of that.